# Why "if(!session_id() Then Do This" Condition Triggers When Session ID Already Exists?

Tags: php, mysqli, sessionid

Trying to build a pagination that works in 3 phases: Start, Midway, End.

QUESTIONS:

Q1. 
I need to know why following line never triggers when I press the ENTER and page loads. Lines 4-11.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['form_step']))//Q1. WHY THIS 'IF' NEVER TRIGGERS WHEN PRESSING 'ENTER' AND LOADING PAGE AND THIS LINE IS UNCOMMENTED ?
{
    unset( $_SESSION['form_step'] );
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    echo "Form Step:"; echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "Line: 10";
}
```

Q2. I need to know why the following IF gets triggered when I click any numbered links (eg page 2, page 3, Next Page, Previous Page) since session id already exists. It should only trigger if session id doesn't exist.
NOTE: This still gets triggered even if I delete/comment-out the lines 4-11 mentioned above on Q1.

```
if(!session_id()) //Q2. WHY THIS IF GETS TRIGGERED WHEN CLICKING ANY NUMBERED PAGE LINKS (ON PAGINATION SECTION (EG PAGE 1 2 3 ETC.)) SINCE SESSION ID ALREADY EXISTS DUE TO ['form_step'] = 'end' ?
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
    echo session_id();
    echo "Line: 20<br>";
}
```

Q3. 
When numbered links on pagination section (eg. Page 2, Next Page, Previous Page, etc.) are clicked, should I re-count the row matches using $sql_query_1 from result_count() or should I leave the code as it currently is ?

NOTE: I am aware of these stackover flow links so don't bother mentioning them:

> A). Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?
>
> > B). Should I manually check for errors when calling "mysqli_stmt_prepare"?

NOTE: 
Am beginner. Still on: Procedural style prepared statements mysqli.
Not yet into: Oop Pdo.

Would appreciate sample code demonstrations in them formats only.

I got a few questions written on the code comments where I am stuck and puzzled.

SCRIPT: 
This is a one/single page script. And so, different params in the url trigger different parts (functions) of the script.

1. At "Start" phase, page loads displaying webform.
   When Form is submitted, "midway" phase counts mysql matching rows using $sql_query_1 from result_count().
2. Then rows are fetched using $sql_query_2 in pagination().
3. If you click any numbered links on pagination section (eg. page 2, page 3, next page, previous page, etc.) then again only the matching rows are fetched using $sql_query_2 from pagination().

INITIAL URL:
http://localhost/power.page/pagination_test_simple.php

PAGINATION URL SAMPLES:
http://localhost/power.page/pagination_test_simple.php?form_type=search&query_type=select&form_step=end&page_limit=2&page=2

http://localhost/power.page/pagination_test_simple.php?form_type=search&query_type=select&form_step=end&page_limit=2&page=3

NOTE: Note the "form_step=" in the urls.

DEV MODE CODE:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_SESSION['form_step']))//Q1. WHY THIS 'IF' NEVER TRIGGERS WHEN PRESSING 'ENTER' AND LOADING PAGE AND THIS LINE IS UNCOMMENTED ?
{
    unset( $_SESSION['form_step'] );
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    echo "Form Step:"; echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "Line: 11";
}



if(!session_id()) //Q2. WHY THIS IF GETS TRIGGERED WHEN CLICKING ANY NUMBERED PAGE LINKS (ON PAGINATION SECTION (EG PAGE 1 2 3 ETC.)) SINCE SESSION ID ALREADY EXISTS DUE TO ['form_step'] = 'end' ?
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';
    echo session_id();
    echo "Line: 20<br>";
}

//$_SESSION['form_step'] = 'start';//DELETE THIS
if(isset($_SESSION['form_step']) && $_SESSION['form_step'] == 'start')//Only run this IF or one of the upcoming ELSEIFs when page is loaded due to page refresh or ENTER pressed or numbered page links clicked on pagination section (eg. page 1 2 3 etc.).
{
    echo "Line: 26<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
    if(!isset($_GET['form_type']) && empty($_GET['form_type']))
    {
        die("Invalid Form!");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['form_type'] = $_GET['form_type'];
        echo "Line: 34<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE

        if(!isset($_GET['query_type']) && empty($_GET['query_type']))
        {
            die("Invalid Query!");
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['query_type'] = $_GET['query_type'];
            echo "Line: 43<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
            if(!function_exists($_SESSION['form_type']))//eg. $_SESSION['search']. This should trigger the search() function.
            {
                echo "Line: 46<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
                die("Invalid Form!");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Line: 51<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
                $_SESSION['form_type']();
            }
        }
    }
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['form_step']) && $_SESSION['form_step'] == 'midway')//Only run this ELSEIF or the next one or the previous one when page is loaded due to page refresh or ENTER pressed or numbered page links clicked on pagination section (eg. page 1 2 3 etc.).
{
    echo "Line: 59<br>";
    die("invalid Query!");
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['form_step']) && $_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end')//Only run this ELSEIF or the previous one or the IF before that, when page is loaded due to page refresh or ENTER pressed or numbered page links clicked on pagination section (eg. page 1 2 3 etc.).
{
    echo "Line: 64<br>";
    pagination();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML">
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device=width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<?php
function search()
{echo "Line: 79<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?form_type=<?php echo $_SESSION['form_type'];?>&query_type=<?php echo $_SESSION['query_type'];?>&form_step=midway&page_limit=2&page=1" method='post' enctype='plain/text'>
    <?php
    //Added '*' (asterisk) to indicate the 'Text Field' is a 'required' one.
    echo "<label for=\"first_name\">First Name *:</label>
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"first_name\" placeholder=\"First Name\" value = \"\">";?>
    <br>
    <?php
    echo "<label for=\"marital_status\">Marital Status *:</label>";
    echo "<select name=\"marital_status\">";
    echo "<option value=\"single\">Single</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"married\">Married</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
    </form>
    <?php
    function result_count()
    {
        echo "result_count function started<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
        if(isset($_SESSION['form_step']) && $_SESSION['form_step'] == 'midway')
        {echo "Line: 102<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE

            //Connect to Database. (DB_SERVER, BD_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME).
            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","powerpage");
            $conn->set_charset('utf8mb4'); //Always set Charset.

            if($conn === false)
            {
                die("ERROR: Connection Error!. " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $sql_query_1 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE first_name = ? AND marital_status = ?";
            $stmt_1 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_1,$sql_query_1))
            {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_1,"ss",$_POST["first_name"],$_POST["marital_status"]);             
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_1);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt_1,$row_count);
                mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt_1);
                $_SESSION["row_count"] = $row_count;
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt_1);
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }
        $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'end';
        echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
        echo "Line: 128<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
        pagination();
        }
    }

    function pagination()
    {
        echo "pagination function started<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
        if(isset($_SESSION['form_step']) && $_SESSION['form_step'] == 'end')
        {echo "Line: 137<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
            echo $_SESSION['form_step'];//DELETE THIS LINE
            $page_number = $_GET['page'];
            $result_per_page = $_GET['page_limit'];
            $row_start = (($page_number * $result_per_page) - $result_per_page); //Offset (Row Number that 'Starts' on page).
            $row_end = ($page_number * $result_per_page); //Row Number that 'Ends' on page.
            $previous_page = $page_number-1;
            $next_page = $page_number+1;

            echo "Row Start: $row_start<br>";
            echo "Row End: $row_end<br>";

            //Connect to Database. (DB_SERVER, BD_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME).
            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","powerpage");
            $conn->set_charset('utf8mb4'); //Always set Charset.

            if($conn === false)
            {
                die("ERROR: Connection Error!. " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $sql_query_2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = ? AND marital_status = ? LIMIT $row_start,$row_end";
            //$_SESSION['sql_query_2'] = $sql_query_2;
            $stmt_2 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt_2,$sql_query_2))
            {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_2,"ss",$_POST["first_name"],$_POST["marital_status"]);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_2);
                $result_2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt_2);

                $row_count = $_SESSION["row_count"];
                $total_pages = ceil($row_count/$result_per_page);
                echo "TOTAL PAGES: $total_pages<br><br>";
                echo "Line: 171<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_2,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                    //Retrieve Values.
                    $id = $row["id"];
                    $first_name = $row["first_name"];
                    $middle_name = $row["middle_name"];
                    $surname = $row["surname"];
                    $gender = $row["gender"];
                    $marital_status = $row["marital_status"];
                    $working_status = $row["working_status"];

                    echo "Id: $id<br>";
                    echo "First Name: $first_name<br>";
                    echo "Middle Name: $middle_name<br>";
                    echo "Surname: $surname<br>";
                    echo "Gender: $gender<br>";
                    echo "Marital Status: $marital_status<br>";
                    echo "Working Status: $working_status<br>";
                }

                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt_2);
                mysqli_close($conn);

                $i = 1;
                if($page_number>$total_pages)
                {
                    echo "<a href='http://localhost/power.page/pagination_test_simple.php?form_type=";?><?php echo $_SESSION['form_type'];?>&query_type=<?php echo $_SESSION['query_type'];?>&form_step=end&page_limit=2&page=<?php echo $total_pages;?>'><?php echo "<b> ->Final Page<- </b>";?></a><?php 
                }
                else
                {
                    if($i<$total_pages)
                    {
                        echo "<a href='http://localhost/power.page/pagination_test_simple.php?form_type=";?><?php echo $_SESSION['form_type'];?>&query_type=<?php echo $_SESSION['query_type'];?>&form_step=end&page_limit=2&page=<?php echo $next_page;?>'><?php echo " Next Page-> ";?></a><?php 
                    }

                    while($i<=$total_pages)
                    {
                        if($i<$total_pages)
                        {
                            echo "<a href='http://localhost/power.page/pagination_test_simple.php?form_type=";?><?php echo $_SESSION['form_type'];?>&query_type=<?php echo $_SESSION['query_type'];?>&form_step=end&page_limit=2&page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo " $i ";?></a><?php 
                        }
                        elseif($i==$page_number)
                        {
                            echo "<a href='http://localhost/power.page/pagination_test_simple.php?form_type=";?><?php echo $_SESSION['form_type'];?>&query_type=<?php echo $_SESSION['query_type'];?>&form_step=end&page_limit=2&page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo "<b> $i </b>";?></a><?php 
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }

                    if($i<$total_pages)
                    {
                        echo "<a href='http://localhost/power.page/pagination_test_simple.php?form_type=";?><?php echo $_SESSION['form_type'];?>&query_type=<?php echo $_SESSION['query_type'];?>&form_step=end&page_limit=2&page=<?php echo $previous_page;?>'><?php echo " <-Previous Page ";?></a><?php 
                    }
                }
            }
            //die();
        }
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        if(isset($_POST['search']))
        {
            $_SESSION['form_step'] = 'midway';
            echo $_SESSION['form_step'];//DELETE THIS LINE
            echo "Line: 237<br>";//DELETE THIS LINE
            result_count();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: add `session_start();` at the top, before or after `error_reporting(E_ALL);` but before any call to `$_SESSION`

Comment: @Professor Abronsius, I did as you suggested. I now get error: Notice: Undefined index: form_step in C:\xampp\htdocs\power.page\pagination_test_SIMPLE.php on line 11.

Comment: @Professor Abronsius,

I can't add session_start(); at the top, because the session had already started when I loaded the page on the 1st instance. Now, the 1st instance shows you SERP. When you clickover to the 2nd page on SERP, the same page loads again. Since the session had already started on the 1st instance then I should not start again on the 2nd instance (2nd load). Hence cannot start session at the top of the page. Hence, the condition:
if(isset($_SESSION['form_step'])
{
    unset( $_SESSION['form_step'] );

Comment: Any page that needs to maintain the session needs `session_start()` - it isn't a `"one time, set and forget"` type thing - if the session is needed across 10 pages those 10 pages must have `session_start`

Answer (score 0):

I can't add commet but you are getting error on line 11 because of this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['form_step']))//Q1. WHY THIS 'IF' NEVER TRIGGERS WHEN PRESSING 'ENTER' AND LOADING PAGE AND THIS LINE IS UNCOMMENTED ?
{
    unset( $_SESSION['form_step'] );
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    echo "Form Step:"; echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "Line: 11";
}
```

You cant unset session and call in echo because is destroyed

```
if(isset($_SESSION['form_step']))//Q1. WHY THIS 'IF' NEVER TRIGGERS WHEN PRESSING 'ENTER' AND LOADING PAGE AND THIS LINE IS UNCOMMENTED ?
{
    //unset( $_SESSION['form_step'] ); This line is problem
    //session_unset(); This line is problem
    //session_destroy();  This line is problem
    echo "Form Step:"; echo $_SESSION['form_step'];
    echo "Line: 11";
}
```